# Java Swing: adding ScrollPane to JPanel

Tags: java, swing

Trying to add a vertical scroll bar to one of the panels in my user interface. Nothing is happening. Related segment below:

```
outputPanel= new JPanel();      
outputPanel.setLayout(null);
outputPanel.setBackground(Color.decode("#ecb3ff"));
scrollPane= new JScrollPane(outputPanel);
scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(700,700));  
scrollPane.setViewportView(outputPanel);        
frame.add(scrollPane);

scrollPane.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Please do not use obscenities in your posts. It has been removed for you. Note that other users may have flagged your post as "rude or abusive" leading to possible rep loss or suspension. Please read [Be Nice](https://superuser.com/help/be-nice): "Avoid vulgar terms and anything sexually suggestive"

Comment: Please post a valid [mcve], code that we can copy, paste, compile and run without modification. Also understand that JScrollPanes don't do well with `null` layouts.

Comment: Also no need to add your outputPanel to the JScrollPane's viewport *twice* as you're doing.

Comment: Also, don't call `setVisible(true)` on the JScrollPane. It is visible by default. You call that instead on the JFrame. And I still don't understand your question/problem since the scrollbar is appearing with the code you've posted. No knobs are in the scrollbar yet because your outputPanel sizes itself to the same size as the viewport. Since outputPanel has only a *default* preferred size, the layout of its container will fully determine its size, here the viewport's layout (which is a specialty layout).

Answer (score 0):

```
outputPanel.setLayout(null);
```

Don't use a null layout.

The scrollbar will only appear when the preferred size of the component added to the viewport is greater than the size of the scrollpane.

The preferred size is only calculated when you use layout managers. Since you don't use a layout manager the preferred size is (0, 0) so there is no need to display an active scrollbar.

Read the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).